# Rhino .OutRef incompatible with .Throw?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a method with out parameters and that may throw an exception. I want to test this behavior with a Rhino mock, so I do :

```
Expect.Call(() => mymethod(null, null, out integer1, out integer2))
                 .IgnoreArguments().OutRef(1, 2).Throw(new Exception());
```

But it appears pretty clearly that the exception is thrown before the out parameters are initialized.

Did I do something wrong or is it the normal rhino behavior ?
How would you address this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a bug in Rhino.Mocks.  I think using the `.Throw()` method says "when I call this method, throw this exception".  That's all it does -- throws the exception.

I would redesign the code so as not to expect `out` variables to be initialized **AND** an exception be thrown.  When I wrap a method in a `try/catch` block and catch an exception, I assume the method could have died anywhere and I don't make any assumptions about what work may have been accomplished (or not accomplished).

Maybe the code could be split into two methods?

Comment: Well I guess it is... I wanted to assert that parameters are still initialized for one specific kind of exception, but I maybe relying on it is not a recommended behavior. Eventually, refactoring is the solution.